# How to create a offer strip on top of the navbar of the website which can be minimized?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I saw this offer on a website which was being displayed above the navbar.
[image]

It looked like this once clicked on the arrow on the top right corner.
[image]

And how can I make it responsive?

[image]

Can anyone share how to implement such a solution? Are there any already existing solutions which I can reuse?

Comment: did you click and view the page source?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is simple to make one by yourself.
The main steps are:

1. create a div element, fixed to the top, height zero
2. put a button to the top right corner
3. bind an event to the button, when clicked, toggle the height of the div.

Here's an example: http://codepen.io/SLRXXX/pen/YWVdJZ

```js
$('.button').on('click', function () {
  $('.top').toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
.top {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.strip {
  height: 0;
  background-color: yellow;
  transition: height 0.5s;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.top.active .strip{
  height: 40px;
}
.button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 5px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: yellow;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.arrow-down {
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}
.top.active .arrow-down{
  transform: rotate(180deg)
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<div class="top">
  <div class="strip">
    some content
  </div>
  <div class="button">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down arrow-down"></i>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Perfect. I changed height to auto and it became responsive. .top.active .strip{
  height: auto;
}